# How to close WMP automatically when the play ends

Tags: flash-video

I need to close WMP (Window Media Player) automatically display on flash. The code follows.

Main page for a WMP displayed by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   

    var flashvars = {
       shelfXmlData : "/eLibNida/shelf/categoryInClientListXML/${clientId}",
       coverXmlData : "/eLibNida/shelf/coverBookInCategoryXML",
       saverXmlData : "/eLibNida/shelf/screensaverInClientXML/?clientId=${clientId}",
       secureURL:"http://elibrary4.nida.ac.th/Media/crossdomain.xml"
    };  
    var params = {
       menu: "false",
       allowDomain : "always",
       allowscriptaccess: "always",
       allowFullScreen: "true",
       wmode:"opaque"
    };  
    var attribute = {};
    $.post("/eLibNida/shelf/themeInClient/${clientId}",function(theme){                                          

    swfobject.embedSWF("${createLinkTo(dir:'swf',file:'digitalBookShelf"+theme+".swf')}","flash","1920","1080","9.0.0","${createLinkTo(dir:'swf',file:'expressInstall.swf')}",
                        flashvars, params, attribute);
                        })

   });
```

Display WMP by this code:

```
<div id="media" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var thisType = "${contentType}";
    var opacLink = "${opcLink}";

    if(thisType == "WindowClip"){               
        wmv = '<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="1280" HEIGHT="960" 
               CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
               STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..."     
               TYPE="application/x-oleobject">';
        wmv += '<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="${value}">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="true">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="stretchtofit" VALUE="true">';
        wmv += '<PARAM name="loop" VALUE="true">'; 
        wmv += '<EMBED  TYPE="application/x-ms-wmp" SRC="${value}" 
                NAME="MediaPlayer"WIDTH="1280" HEIGHT="960" ShowControls="true" 
                ShowStatusBar="false"ShowDisplay="false" autostart="true" 
                stretchtofit="true" loop="true"</EMBED>';    
        wmv += '</OBJECT>';                                                      
        $("#media").prepend(wmv).width(1280).height(960).css({"margin-top":"50px"});
```

How do I close it?